# How to run scala code inside databricks community edition notebook?

Tags: scala, databricks, databricks-community-edition

Databricks [community edition notebook](https://community.cloud.databricks.com/) allows one to practice [scala guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html) and try examples in real-time. However, the default is set to pySpark and I was wondering how I can run scala code instead?

Comment: just change the main language of the notebook (click on Python). Either select Sclaa as main language when creating the notebook

Comment: i tried this - it didn't work for me with default settings, I think it's expecting pySpark by default

Comment: Just checked on community edition. I can create new notebook with Scala language as default, or I can click to the `(Python)` near the notebook name, and change the primary language for the whole notebook

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that I can use %scala cell magic, i.e. prefixing the cell code with %scala lets you run Scala code inside Databricks community edition notebook!